# echoing in a form after submission

Tags: php, forms, echo

I have a form that send information to a mysql db. Error messages and a confirmation appear to the right of the form in a seperate div so the form action needs to send the user to the same page. I am echoing the field the user types in in case they need to edit something based on the error message that appears. However, if the form is submitted correct, how could i make it so the php does not echo in the form?

```
<?php

$submit = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'submit');
//form data
$fullname = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'fullname');
$email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email');
$business = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'business');
$date = date("Y-m-d");

?>
```

then after other html code....

```
  <div class="wrap">
      <div id="reg">

  <form action='register.php' method='POST'>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
        Your full name:
        </td>
        <td>
        <input type='text' name='fullname' value='<?php echo $fullname;?>'>
        }
        </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        Your email:
        </td>
        <td>
        <input type='text' name='email' value='<?php echo $email;?>'>
        </td>

    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
        Your business:
        </td>
        <td>
        <input type='text' name='business' value='<?php echo $business;?>'>
        </td>

    </tr>






 </table>
 </br>
 <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Register'>

</form>
 </br>       

    </div>
    <?php
 if ($submit)
  {
    //open database
  $connect=mysql_connect("localhost","root","Ryweb1994");
  mysql_select_db("phapsy");


  //check for existence
if($fullname&&$business&&$business)
{

   $queryreg = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users VALUES                           ('','$fullname','$email','$business','$date')");
    echo ("<div id='message'><p>You have been registered! We will send you an email            with login information. Thank you for your interest in Phapsy!<p></div>");

   }
else echo "Please fill in <b>all</b> fields!";

   }


  ?>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Are you still having trouble with this? I see there's an answer selected, but you're still commenting on other answers..?

Comment: selected that one cuz it was the best... i figured a work around myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrap your form around with the `$submit` variable:

```
+ <?php if($submit) { ?>
 <div class="wrap">
  ... 
  <form action='register.php' method='POST'>
  ...
  </form>
</div>
+ <?php }; ?>

    <?php
 if ($submit)
  {
    //open database
  $connect=mysql_connect("localhost","root","Ryweb1994");
  mysql_select_db("phapsy");


  //check for existence
if($fullname&&$business&&$business)
{

   $queryreg = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users VALUES                           ('','$fullname','$email','$business','$date')");
    echo ("<div id='message'><p>You have been registered! We will send you an email            with login information. Thank you for your interest in Phapsy!<p></div>");

   }
else echo "Please fill in <b>all</b> fields!";

   }


  ?>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you say you are echoing the confirmation, you are obviously testing somehow for successful input - but you don't show that code.

So something like `<input type='text' name='fullname' value='<?php if(!$successful){echo $fullname;} ?>'>` would do it

Comment: how would i define the $successful variable?

Comment: Ryan, we aren't here to write your code for you.  We have answered a specific question.  If you can't do something as basic as determine whether an event is successful or not you need to go back to the tutorials websites.

Answer (score 1):

Put the processing logic before the display logic.

Set a variable that reflects whether the database interaction succeeded.

Update your echo statements throughout the form to only print a value if the interaction failed (or failed to validate):

```
<?php $successfullyProcessed = false;

//processing logic
$successfullyProcessed = true;


<input type='text' name='fullname' value='<?php if (!successfullyProcessed) echo $fullname;?>'>
```

Comment: how do i define the variable... i dont really understand

Comment: how would i define the variable of $successfullyProcessed?